# Use Curl SSL Certificate in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: ssl, curl, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_fields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');           
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '0');            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '0');            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'cert.pem');            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  'cert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'mypass');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com:18443/Handler');
```

When I run just this code, everything works properly. (including SSL certificate).

But, When I use this code in WP plugin, there is: `curl_error: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)`

I think there are some hidden filters within Wordpress core and they blocks/edits my ssl Curl request.

How can I avoid WP http curl filters?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

```
$certfile = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/cert.pem';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_fields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');           
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '0');            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '0');            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certfile);            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  $certfile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'mypass');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com:18443/Handler');
```